# Changing grid lines in a log graph in R

Tags: r, grid, line

I am trying to format my graph attached below. I have a line of code

```r
ggline(Titration.Aug.9, x="Dilution",y="X..bound",color="Sample") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10",labels=trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x))) +
theme_minimal() +
labs(x="Dilution",y="% Bound") +
scale_color_brewer(type="Sample",palette="Set1")
```

so that I may change the labels to 10^# and have only my x-axis on a log 10 scale. The problem is that I don't know how to change the grid lines so they are more frequent and less spaced. I have tried to use minor_breaks=seq(0,1e10, 1e10) nested in the scale_x_continuous command. Should I use a different command that encapsulates the whole graph since I want all grid lines to be changed? If so, what should I use?

[image: 1]

[Graph data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EPuI.png)

```
> dput(Titration.Aug.9)
structure(list(Dilution = c(300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 
72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 
300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 
2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 
24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 
218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 
900L, 2700L, 8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L, 300L, 900L, 2700L, 
8100L, 24300L, 72900L, 218700L), X..bound = c(52.74, 40.31, 30.63, 
18.89, 7.57, 0.8, 0.01, 20.23, 11.29, 7.55, 3.24, 0.54, 0.12, 
0.03, 53.27, 46.82, 38.17, 26.77, 11.59, 2.23, 0.07, 69.25, 63.55, 
56.34, 40.95, 19.35, 2.4, 0.05, 75.8, 68.21, 62.82, 40.33, 11.73, 
0.82, 0.04, 85.75, 82.82, 74.29, 46.63, 9.36, 0.24, 0.05, 71.65, 
66.54, 56.63, 33.96, 6.33, 0.19, 0.03, 85.43, 86.49, 75.73, 51.62, 
15.16, 1.05, 0.01, 92.44, 90.13, 85.92, 72.06, 30.08, 3.15, 0.12
), Sample = c("1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", 
"1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 0DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", 
"1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 2DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", 
"1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 3DA", "1mer 4DA", 
"1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", "1mer 4DA", 
"5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", "5mer 0DA", 
"5mer 0DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", 
"5mer 2DA", "5mer 2DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", 
"5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 4DA", "5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", 
"5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDG", 
"5mer 2DA GDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", 
"5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG", "5mer 2DA GDGDG"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -63L))
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can include some example data that would allow us to run your code without needing to make our own. That could be as simple as running `dput(Titration.Aug.9)` and pasting the output into your question. I'm also guessing the picture included here was not produced by the code you included? It looks like a linear y scale.

Comment: Yes of course! Sorry about that. I'll upload now! It is a linear y scan but a log x scale. The image is produced by that line of code that is within the query

Comment: We can't run your code or test solutions using a picture of data--could you please share some sample data using `dput()` like Jon suggests? It's a nice way to make a copy/pasteable version of an R object. We don't even need the whole thing, `dput(Titration.Aug.9[1:16, ])` would give us the first 16 rows, and if your data has unneeded columns you can also specify only the needed columns in the `dput`.

Comment: Very sorry! I think that should be what you are looking for. (I am kind of new to coding if it weren't so painfully obvious before; but, any help is sincerely appreciated!) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get a graph with 1 minor break in between every major break pair--unlike your picture. But you're right to try to use the `minor_breaks` argument to add more of them:

```
ggline(Titration.Aug.9, x="Dilution",y="X..bound",color="Sample") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans="log10",
    labels=trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x)),
    minor_breaks = 10^(seq(0, 7, by = 0.25))
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Dilution",y="% Bound") +
  scale_color_brewer(type="Sample",palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute saint! Thank you so much! I was not inputting the right scale for the minor breaks command (i.e the 10^(seq(#1,#2, by=#)) thank you so much!